# dirección dinámica firebase java swing

Tags: java, firebase, java-swing

hola he establecido una conexión con firebase desde un programa java echo en netbeans

```
   refreshToken = new FileInputStream
    ("C:\\Users\\pc1\\Desktop\\sistemas java\\src\\main\\java\\Paquetes\\adminFirebase.json");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder() 
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://miuniversidad-65dc5.firebaseio.com")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

mi pregunta es como puedo cambiar la dirección estática que se muestra por un archivo ya existente en mi proyecto  ya que si hago el jar y lo traslado a un lugar diferente me marcara un error he probado con un archivo File  y dejando simplemente esta dirección pero aun asi falla **sistemas 
 java\src\main\java\Paquetes\adminFirebase.json** 
alguien ya ha logrado solucionar ese problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a crear un JAR, podrías usar algo como esto:

```
File file = new File("./adminFirebase.json");
//...
refreshToken = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Te podría servir.

Comment: funciono solamente que saque el archivo a la raiz interna del proyecto